# Crosstab Query (Obtain week number)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to make a cross-query and I need to obtain the week number. But my request is displayed empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
    TRANSFORM Sum(Delivered.Count) AS [Sum-Count]
SELECT Delivered.Merchandise
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Delivered ON Orders.OrderNumber = Delivered.OrderNumber
WHERE (((Orders.OrderDate) Like "Like”*.*.1999”"))
GROUP BY Delivered.Merchandise
PIVOT DatePart("dw",[OrderDate]) In (36,37,39,40,42);
```

---

I solved this problem. It was necessary change

```
WHERE (((Orders.OrderDate) Like "Like”*.*.1999”"))
```

to

```
WHERE (((Договоры.[ДатаДоговора]) Like ("*.*.1999")))
```

Thank you to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepart "dw" will return a number from 1-7.  You are looking for numbers between 36 and 42.  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) will help you.

Also, if OrderDate is a date or datetime datatype, change

```
WHERE (((Orders.OrderDate) Like "Like”*.*.1999”"))
```

to

```
WHERE DatePart("yyyy", Orders.OrderDate) = 1999
```

Comment: but if i used "ww" or "wk" then the same result

Comment: Start by ensuring that you have orders for those weeks in 1999.

Comment: apear messagebox with "Invalid procedure call" P.S yeah, i have orders in this weeks in 1999. It's looks so strange(